# Visual Studio 2012 Express: How to Debug with Custom Webserver

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-express

I have IIS 7 installed on my machine. With Visual Studio 2010 Professional I can attach to the IIS process and debug correctly.

I noticed that Visual Studio 2012 Express does not appear have that option. However it does have the option for a custom web server to be used during debugging. It only asks for the Base URL which I assume would be `http://localhost/`. However I get the following error when I try to debug with that setting:

```
"The web server is not configured correctly."
```

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a custom web server.  That's a custom web URL.  That allows you to specify the URL to use when you execute the debugger.  That doesn't mean the debugger will use that process.

VS Express doesn't allow attaching to other process, as far as I know.  You would have to buy the Standard version, or you could try one of the free development environments like SharpDevelop.

Comment: Thank you for your help Mystere Man. I've updated my question with a screenshot of of the dialog at Debug > PublicSite Properties. It clearly has a "custom webserver" option under the Server section. Do you still believe this doesn't change the webserver? I'm just a little confused :)

Comment: @jmotes - It changes the url, which may be a different server.. What exactly are you trying to do?  Please don't say change the web server... I mean, what is ultimately the reason you are doing this.

Comment: I just want to be able to debug the same website that I can view at http://computername/project_alias/. The projects that I am working with have all been built and tested only in standard IIS environments and URL rewriting, etc. don't always work correctly when running with the VS webserver.

Comment: @jmotes - Why don't you use IIS Express?

Comment: That would probably be fine if it would work. I assumed kleinkie's response wouldn't work either if I couldn't set a custom web server in Express. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you once again! The option to use IIS Express showed up in the Website dropdown when I selected the website folder in my solution. Seems to work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use Attach To Process on IIS process, when using Visual Studio Express for Web as your dev IDE:

- Open your web site project in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web,
  and browse your dev website in a browser - You can do it by Ctrl+F5 in VS (start without debugging) - this will run w3wp.exe (ISS Application Pool Process - this process will run when your project Web Location is HTTP)
- Open Visual Studio express 2012 for **windows desktop**. yes. for "windows desktop" - here will come the trick (-:
- In the VS for desktop - press Ctrl+O (Open File) - and browse to file in website that you want to debug -  [root]/Default.aspx.cs for example.
  Now in the Default.aspx.cs code, set a Breakpoint - for example in
  Page_Load event code
- In the VS for desktop - go to Debug menu and select Attach To Process...
  In the Attach To Process dialog - in the Available Process list select your IIS process: w3wp.exe
  Now press Attach button
- Go to your browser and run the /Default.aspx page

Result:
The website run in IIS process, will stop in the breakpoint in the VS for desktop, and you can debug it.

Notes:

- This will work only if your website project Web Location is HTTP (this configured when creating the website project in the VS. [Google for instructions](http://www.google.com/search?q=Creating%20a%20Local%20IIS%20Web%20Site%20in%20Visual%20Studio))
- I did it on 2012 version, and it may work on other versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

See if this post could possibly help you. Make Web Development Easier with IIS Express: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/396569/Make-Web-Development-Easier-with-IIS-Express

I don't have express on my PC but as far as I know, VS Express supports the use of a local IIS web server or a custom web server which means you should be able to debug using either. If you use Local IIS web server, you will need to enter the correct URL (usually "http://localhost/applicationname"), if you use custom web server you would simply add a port instead of the /applicationame such as "http://localhost:54124"

Comment: Thanks kleinkie. Do you know if this possible with Visual Studio Express? NV - just now saw your edit.

Comment: Got it to work after @Mystere-Man in comments to his answer verified the IIS Express option was available. I enabled it by (1) selecting the website folder in my solution (PublicSite in my case) which caused the Project dropdown to be renamed to Website, then (2) choosing "Use IIS Express..." from that dropdown.